# shading area between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a graph with three vertices and want to shade the area between the edges following the edges 1 to 3 to 2 to 1.  (code below)

[image]

The first problem I get is with the curve (in red). Before the curve no problems, the second segment starts in 3 at a different point along the edge of 3. After the curve however in 2 the third segment starts at the position the second segment arrived.

This I could patch by adding a extra position. Still the shading is not at the right position.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzstyle{knop}=[circle,minimum size=14,inner sep=0pt,draw]
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
%- part shaded area missing
\path [fill=lightgray,draw] (p1.south east) to (p3.north west) to (p3) 
    to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p2.north east) to (p1);
%- red line continues at same position?
\path [draw=red,very thin] (p1) to (p3) to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p1);
%- paint over to get the nodes right 
%\node[knop,fill=white] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
%\node[knop,fill=white] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
%\node[knop,fill=white] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the red line continues at same position, this is how the path works. Of course, you could do, say,  `\path (p1) to (p3) (p2) to (p1);` to have two separate paths.

Comment: Indeed, as separate \path's there was not problem. For the fill I needed a single \path, and was very surprised that node 3 gave different results from node 2.

Comment: I added more explanations to my answer. My previous comment was not entirely correct, I confused beginning with end. I do not think it is absolutely obvious why that happens, but there are at least to ways to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: in order to shade an area, you need a continuous path. If you have gaps in your path, then Ti*k*Z will only shade the last stretch. This happens in your path

```
\path [fill=lightgray,draw] (p1.south east) to (p3.north west) to (p3) 
    to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p2.north east) to (p1);
```

Even though this does not seem immediately in ones eye, you effectively do that here since the `to` operation together with an extended node will draw the path to the `\pgfpointshapeborder`, see p. 1031 of the pgfmanual. That's why I draw the path in the above between explicit anchors, and use the `backgrounds` library in order not to wipe out parts of the nodes.

This is illustrated in the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{knop/.style={circle,minimum size=14,inner sep=0pt,draw},
explain/.style={font=\sffamily,text width=2cm,anchor=north,anchor=north}}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=TL]
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
%- part shaded area missing
\path [fill=lightgray,draw=blue] (p1.south east) to (p2.north east) to (p2) 
    to [out=-45,in=225] (p3) to (p3.north west) to (p1);
%- red line continues at same position?
\path [draw=red,very thin] (p1) to (p3) to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p1);
\end{scope}
\node[explain] at (TL.south) {your proposal};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,local bounding box=TR]
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
%- part shaded area missing
\path [fill=lightgray,draw=blue] (p1.south east) to (p3.north west) to (p3) 
to[out=-135,in=-45] (p2) to (p2.north east) to (p1);
%- red line continues at same position?
\path [draw=red,very thin] (p1) to (p3) to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p1);
\end{scope}
\node[explain] at (TR.south) {the problem is symmetric};
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=BL]
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
%- part shaded area missing
\path [fill=lightgray,draw=blue] (p1.south west) to (p2.north east) to (p2.-45) 
    to [out=-45,in=225] (p3) to (p3.north west) to (p1);
%- red line continues at same position?
\path [draw=red,very thin] (p1) to (p3) to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p1);
\end{scope}
\node[explain] at (BL.south) {anchor inserted};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,local bounding box=BR]
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
%- part shaded area missing
\path [fill=lightgray,draw=blue] (p1.south east) to (p3.north west) to (p3.-135) 
to[out=-135,in=-45] (p2) to (p2.north east) to (p1);
%- red line continues at same position?
\path [draw=red,very thin] (p1) to (p3) to [out=225,in=-45] (p2) to (p1);
\end{scope}
\node[explain] at (BR.south) {anchor inserted};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This shows that the problem is symmetric, as one could have expected. It also shows that you have effectively a gap in your path, but I agree that it is not obvious that you have one rather than two gaps. Somehow Ti*k*Z skips over the first gap but not over the second one. Why that is, I don't know.

The MWE also shows how to fix this: add one additional anchor to the path, such that there is no gap.

However, I am wondering if you really want to wipe out parts of the nodes, or in fact attempt to draw something like the following.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{knop/.style={circle,minimum size=14,inner sep=0pt,draw,fill=white}}
\node[knop] (p1) at (0,1.2) {$1$} ;
\node[knop] (p2) at (-1.2,0) {$2$} ;
\node[knop] (p3) at (1.2,0) {$3$} ;
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
%- loop is not a problem
\path [fill=lightgray,draw,looseness=6,loop] (p1) to [out=45,in=135] (p1);
\path [fill=lightgray,draw=red,very thin] (p1.center) to  (p3.center) 
    to [out=225,in=-45] (p2.center) to (p1.center);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The backgrounds library is of course a tool I completely missed!

Comment: +1 A very good explanation can be found on p 245, I quote: However, for most other shapes, some path construction operations like -- try to be “clever” when they are asked to draw a line from such a coordinate or to such a coordinate. When you say `(x)--(1,1)`, the `--` path operation will not draw a line from the center of `x`, but from the border of `x` in the direction going towards `(1,1)`. Likewise, `(1,1)--(x)` will also have the line end on the border in the direction coming from `(1,1).` The `TikZ` manual is a real maquis!

Comment: @AndréC Thanks! However, this is the "easy" part. In these paths there are two occurrences of this, which seem to get treated differently.

Comment: No, they are treated the same way, at least it seems to me.

Comment: @AndréC Well, could you please compare the blue contour and the shaded area?  Just look at the upper both pictures. There is always *one* (rather than two) mismatch, and it is always at the first node.

Comment: add `opacity=.5` on all operation, you will see !

Comment: @AndréC Sorry, I do not need to do that. In the top left and right examples, the same path gets filled, the only difference is that it gets run through in opposite directions. Naively one would expect that the filling areas will coincide. Do you agree with this statement? The issue is that the filled areas do not coincide. Do you agree?

Comment: in the figure at the top left replace with: `\path [fill=lightgray,draw=blue,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (p1.south east) to (p2.north east) to (p2) to [out=-45,in=225] (p3) to (p3.north west) to (p1);` you will understand.

Comment: @AndréC Yes, I did that. And repeated it for the top right path. In both cases the area bounded by the blue path and the shaded area do not coincide. Do you agree?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85946/discussion-between-andrec-and-marmot).